# USNO REST API in R

Tags: r, api, jsonlite

I am trying to extract moonrise and set times from the [US Naval Observatory Rest API](https://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/api#rstt) using the htrr and jsonlite packages. However, I keep getting an error saying, please supply dates in an MM/DD/YYYY format. Which I believe I am, so quite confused.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

GET("https://aa.usno.navy.mil/api/rstt/oneday?date=09/20/2005&coords=47.60,-122.33")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is confusing, but it seems that we may need to pass in the YYYY-MM-DD format

```
out <- GET("https://aa.usno.navy.mil/api/rstt/oneday?date=2005-09-20&coords=47.60,-122.33")
```

-output

```
out
Response [https://aa.usno.navy.mil/api/rstt/oneday?date=2005-09-20&coords=47.60,-122.33]
  Date: 2022-07-24 18:43
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 1.26 kB
{
  "apiversion": "3.0.0", 
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      -122.33, 
      47.6
    ], 
    "type": "Point"
  }, 
  "properties": {
...
```

Then, extract the `content`

```
library(dplyr)
library(rrapply)
> rrapply(content(out)$properties$data, how = "bind")
  closestphase.day closestphase.month closestphase.phase closestphase.time closestphase.year       curphase day day_of_week fracillum isdst label
1               18                  9          Full Moon             02:01              2005 Waning Gibbous  20     Tuesday       92% FALSE  NULL
  month moondata.1.phen moondata.1.time moondata.2.phen moondata.2.time moondata.3.phen moondata.3.time sundata.1.phen sundata.1.time
1     9            Rise           02:57   Upper Transit           09:57             Set           17:15            Set          02:13
      sundata.2.phen sundata.2.time       sundata.3.phen sundata.3.time sundata.4.phen sundata.4.time sundata.5.phen sundata.5.time tz year
1 End Civil Twilight          02:43 Begin Civil Twilight          13:23           Rise          13:54  Upper Transit          20:03  0 2005
```

By checking the webpage, it is more evident i.e. `format` specified seems to be incorrect

[image]

Comment: Nice find ... there goes the argument for adhering to the documented formats.

Comment: Yes! Great catch on that date. I was trusting the documentation too much. I'll email them and let them know, thank you.